# `setattr` fails with `AttributeError` in CPython?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

For some reason this fails in Python 3.8:

```
setattr(iter(()), '_hackkk', 'bad idea')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-c046f8521130> in <module>
----> 1 setattr(iter(()), '_hackkk', 'bad idea')

AttributeError: 'tuple_iterator' object has no attribute '_hackkk'
```

How do I attach random data where I shouldn't, i.e., on an iterator or a generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach data only to objects, which have `__dict__`-member. Not all objects have it - for example builtin classes like `int`, `float`, `list` and so on do not. This is an optimization, because otherwise instances of those classes would need too much memory - a dictionary has a quite large memory footprint.

Also for normal classes one could use [`__slots__`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/5769463), thus removing `__dict__`-member and prohibiting dynamic addition of attributes to an object of this class. E.g.

```
class A:
    pass
setattr(A(),'b', 2)
```

works, but

```
class B:
    __slots__ = 'b'
setattr(B(),'c', 2)
```

doesn't work, as class `B` has no slot with name `c` and no `__dict__`.

Thus, the answer to your question is: for some classes (as the `tuple_iterator`) you cannot.

If you really need to, you can wrap `tuple_iterator` in a class with `__dict__` and append the new attribute to the wrapper-object:

```
class IterWrapper:
    def __init__(self, it):
        self.it=it
    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.it)   
    def __iter__(self): # for testing
        return self
```

and now:

```
iw=IterWrapper(iter((1,2,3)))
setattr(iw, "a", 2)
print(iw.a)          # prints 2
print(list(iw))      # prints [1,2,3]
```

has the desired behavior.